# error in cloned substring() function in js

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I am trying to make a function in js that checks whether a substring exists in main string. For eg:- main = 111010 and substring = 011 should return false as substring does not exists in main string but my code returns true. Here is the code below.

```
var string = "111010",
substr = "011";     

var found=false;

outter:for(var i=0;i<string.length;i++){
    if(string.charAt(i)==substr.charAt(0)){                   
        var k=i+1;
        inner:for(j=1;j<substr.length;j++){
            if(string.charAt(k++)==substr.charAt(j)){
                found=true;
                continue inner;
            }else{
              continue outter;
            }
        }
    }
}

if(found!=false){
    console.log("y")
}else{
    console.log("n");
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use `string.indexOf(substr) != -1` ?

Comment: Yes i can use the api provided by language but I want to do it on my own so that I can know how it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to re-initialize the `found` variable.

```
var string = "111010",
substr = "0110";     

var found=false;

for(var i=0;i<string.length;i++){
    if(string.charAt(i)==substr.charAt(0)){                   
        var k=i+1;
        for(j=1; j < substr.length;j ++)
            if(string.charAt(k++)==substr.charAt(j)){
                found=true;
            }else{
               found = false; // <<--this
               break;
            }
        if(found) break;   
    }
}

if(found!=false){
    console.log("y")
}else{
    console.log("n");
}
```

Your code always returns true if it ever find a single common letter between your `string` and `substring`.

And please, **DO NOT USE LABELS**, they are simply bad. Thanks!

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/fer52ufd/

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fer52ufd/1/) is how your code should actually be.

```
var found = false;

for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) { // starting position
    found = true; // All letters match,  prove the opposite

    for (j = 0; j < substr.length; j++) { // Compare the given string with the string starting at i
        if (string.charAt(i + j) != substr.charAt(j)) { // If one letter does not match, stop searching
            found = false;
            break;
        }       
    }

    if (found) break;
}
```

- Why treat the first letter separately?
- Don't use labels
- Don't search for the match, search for letters that do not match and, if you find none, the strings match.
- Do not use unnecessary index variables (as k), the position of the letter on the needle string is `j` and in the hay string is `i+j`

Comment: Let me check this out

Comment: now it outputs false even when substring exists. Try this one out main=111010, sub=101

Comment: Because the loop is not stopped when you find a match. See my edit.

Comment: it worked, still was not outputting true for single number(main = 111010, substring = 1) but I found a hack to fix it.Thanks.:)

Comment: See again my update for a cleaner version of your code.

Comment: I'm confused about the placement of the `found = true` line. It's being executed over and over again after each character comparison. Surely it is cleaner to place it between the two `for` statements. The initialization of `found` at the top also seems completely redundant.

Comment: @torazaburo Look at my update. His code does it's just, but it is not a clean code. It has a lot of redundant code. And yes, in my code "found" is wrongly place, it has to be initialized before the loop. And first initialization is not redundant. If the string is the `empty string` the for never gets executed, so you output directly the `found` variable, which would be `undefined`.

Comment: @Cristy: also, to nitpick, in `for (var i = 0; i < string.length` it should be `i < string.length - substr.length`.

Comment: @torazaburo Yes, that could be an optimization, but if you want something better you can do it in `O(N)` by using `hashing`, known as the Rabin-Karp algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm (or something pretty simillar)

Comment: I'm just saying that there's no need to check substring matches starting at less than the length of the substring from the end of the string. Sure, for something better I'd go with Boyer-Moore.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to check that:

```
var string = "111010", substr = "011";
var test = string.indexOf(substr);

if (test >= 0) { 
    alert('yes');
} else {
    alert('no');
}
```

Comment: I know how I can solve this problem using indexOf function but I was asked to achieve this same functionality without using any api